# Matching Regex for JSON

Tags: python, regex

This is like my source code (Not my real Pipeline of Jenkins) I use both imperative decelerative (imperative so I could create non defaults parameters from plugins)

```
node {
    timeout(unit: 'SECONDS', time: 5) {
        stage("One"){
            sleep 10
            echo 'hello'
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
  agent any

  parameters {
    choice(
      description: 'Run flyway database migration using latest master branch from prices in what environment?',
      name: 'environment',
      choices: ['PRE', 'PRO']
    )
  }

  stages {
    stage("Wat") {
      steps {
        echo "selectedEnvironment: ${params.environment}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking for regex so I could get the imperative part and the decelerative part.

I found this regex:

```
import regex
patternOfJson = regex.compile(r'\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}')
```

that print me that output without the word before the { }.

```
{
    timeout(unit: 'SECONDS', time: 5) {
        stage("One"){
            sleep 10
            echo 'hello'
        }
    }
}
```

How can I print the same part (like this regex) but with the word before it? (pipeline, node...)?

Comment: First, it is not going to work if there are unpaired `{` or `}` inside strings (e.g. `description: 'Run flyway {.....'`). Second, if you do not care, use a regex subroutine, `[x.group() for x in regex.finditer(r'\w+\s*(\{(?:[^{}]|(?1))*})', text)]`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BILsLv/1).

Comment: for some reason it does not return me the same as the first regex. its seperate the { } to other parts. I want to keep like the regex I gave in the question just if there is a word before that it print it too.

Comment: I think it [returns just what you asked for](https://tio.run/##VZJBb@MgEIXv/IqRtRLQTaJWq71YqnLYzXVTtYcemq5E7YmNZA8IxptEqX97Fjtuk3IAwUNv3nzgD1w7@nE62da7wBCwwr1g3DPcQ5BSkisRjgLSYNui61h1ZDkH@bT6tf7z@0nORiGHn3q6N4zIpkKVrQkzfTkdlQbRw93tl0MsageyxqZx8lPoxXnuhfDWY2PpnCQ5E4Ohg0gbb4JpkTHEqXpysgWqyaXEWATr2TpKkR87gm1z2JkDlIbNm4kIra2CGXTooqUKGsMYGVoTkym8BUNFDdvgWvAhGUewBLvaMCD9s8FRm8Is5WyqR2ZAIa@0T@kcLObwIh8eVwlbWtbydVS1GBoVE7ePViaIz4azC9sUy8cr0iO6LGKDBWO5uhTO4dtxpBMXV3H6THylOxJODy22LsB@6G78A4utpdImBCrIze77Jt6ozVEt85e/x/71XS3vtL7p9fD46a/ofDRLgIgV7BdVcJ1XegbZfD7PZhDR32cbykCfTv8B). Check the *Output* section